# glMultiDrawArrays in QT?

Tags: qt, opengl

It appears that glMultiDrawArrays is not available by default in QT's Opengl library. Is there anyway I can make it available in QT ?

Comment: I am coding on QT on Windows XP.  It does appear that QT only supports function call ups to Opengl 1.1

Answer (score 3):

Qt is only responsible for creating an OpenGL context, not for providing OpenGL calls.

Try using a loader library like [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) or [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) in order to access modern OpenGL features.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as Qt's OpenGL library, OpenGL is handled by your OS, Qt only provides a wrapper for platform-independent OpenGL Context and Window creation.

Whatever that function is available or not depends on your OpenGL drivers, OpenGL headers, etc.